# Is it possible to edit the exisiting html code on a wix website

Tags: html, velo

I am working on a website with wix and the description of the page is broken, I edit it in wix, but it's not updating, I found the error while looking through the source code using chrome, I need to change the HTML code but I can't find where I can do that, can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Corvid to Wix, then you can.

https://www.wix.com/corvid/corvid/all-documentation

"With Corvid by Wix you can work with our APIs and add JavaScript to your site.  You add and edit your code in our integrated development environment (IDE) available directly in the Wix Editor when you enable Corvid. This IDE provides syntax checking and basic code analysis for your code."